# how to get the producer client id or entity-name list in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I'd like to set quota for each Producer and Consumer. For example the following command to set the quotas:

```
./kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 
  --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1048,consumer_byte_rate=2097'
  --entity-name test-client --entity-type clients
```

my question is that: how can I get the entity-name? because right now there are hundreds of producers and consumers are using Kafka, but I don't know their ids/names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--entity-default` to apply the quota to all client-ids. This is mentioned in the [Setting quotas](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quotas) section in the documentation:

> It is possible to set default quotas for each (user, client-id), user
>   or client-id group by specifying --entity-default option instead of
>   --entity-name.

Your command would be:

```
./kafka-configs.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 
  --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=1048,consumer_byte_rate=2097'
  --entity-default --entity-type clients
```